# How to compare two operands that are more than 4 bits using a 74181 ALU?

Tags: proteus, alu

I have this 74181 ALU in Proteus.

I want to compare two operands that are 8 bits.

How should I change my circuit?

[image]

Comment: Use more than one 74181.

Comment: so how should I connect them?

Comment: [Have a look here.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/312354/74181-alu-not-working-properly-cascaded-to-add-8-bit-numbers) and in the [74181 datasheet,](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls181.pdf) of course.

Comment: @MahdiAspanani The 74181 was designed from the ground up to be extensible to wider word sizes. In fact, I used them with the first 8-bit computer I ever built, in 1974, using wire-wrap. I had no training, no education at all in electronics, and I was able to use the 7400 series logic book from TI and the datasheets to work out these details on my own. Today, you have the internet and boards like this to clarify details -- none of which was available to me at the time. You have a very low barrier today and should be able to skate over it, easily. Are you saying you cannot make a small effort?